# Wait until the timer ticks specific number of times

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make my program do nothing until my timer ticks twice (2 seconds in total). 
I'm using the following code, and the timer won't work unless I take out the while statement.

```
timer = 0;
Console.WriteLine("timer start ");
timer1.Start();
while (timer < 2);
Console.WriteLine("timer ends");

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(timer);
    timer++;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be using  `System.Timers.Timer`, that will run in a seperate thread, See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx):

From above link:

`System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

> If you're looking for a metronome, you've come to the wrong place. The timer events raised by this timer class are synchronous with respect to the rest of the code in your Windows Forms app. This means that application code that is executing will never be preempted by an instance of this timer class (assuming you don't call Application.DoEvents).

`System.Timers.Timer`

> The .NET Framework documentation refers to the System.Timers.Timer class as a server-based timer that was designed and optimized for use in multithreaded environments. Instances of this timer class can be safely accessed from multiple threads. Unlike the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, the System.Timers.Timer class will, by default, call your timer event handler on a worker thread obtained from the common language runtime (CLR) thread pool. **This means that the code inside your Elapsed event handler must conform to a golden rule of Win32 programming: an instance of a control should never be accessed from any thread other than the thread that was used to instantiate it**.

Working Code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    System.Timers.Timer  tmr = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    volatile int timer;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer = 0;

        tmr.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(tmr_Elapsed);
        tmr.Start();
        while (timer < 2) ;
        tmr.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("timer ends");
    }

    void tmr_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(timer);
        timer++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good, informative answer, but I suggest you put some locking around the access to the `timer` variable for memory visibility.  Or use the `volatile` keyword.

Comment: Still Mark, why don't you synchronize the threads? You know, `Monitor.Wait` instead of the constant timer checking...

Comment: @NikoDrašković This example was just to show the OP what the problem was and **one** of ways that it will work.

Comment: I am curious, why would you need locks or `volatile` around  `int timer;` ?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what timer class you're using (that's important).  Assuming it's something like System.Windows.Forms.Timer, the tick is never happening because it's dispatched on the main event loop, and you're tying up the main event loop with your while loop.  If it's a timer class that's not tied to the GUI, it's possible there are memory visibility problems due to the lack of thread synchronization.

I'm also curious why *two* ticks?  Presumably this is simplified code and your timer_tick method is actually doing something more interesting?  If not, you could just Thread.Sleep(2000).  If the tick code does something interesting, you could handle completion in your tick method, like so:

```
timer = 0;
Console.WriteLine("timer start ");
timer1.Start();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(timer);
    if (++timer == 2) {
      Console.WriteLine("timer ends");
      // and you probably want a timer1.Stop() in here too
    }
}
```